# Report Builder Switch Case

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

Wondering if there was a more efficient way to write this expression? Essentially trying to replace an employee number with their name and trying to avoid a very long switch statement or nested replace statement.

For example:

`=Switch(Fields!Operator_Id.Value = "1", "JOHN", Fields!Operator_Id.Value = "2", "JIM", Fields!Operator_Id.Value = "3", "SUE", Fields!Operator_Id.Value = "4", "ALEX", Fields!Operator_Id.Value = "5", "WINSTON", ect...)`

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please update your tags.

Comment: Surely you store the relationship between the value and name in your database? So load the list and then index into it.

Comment: @DaleK What tags would you recommend? Also, this is a legacy system built in the 80's. The data that we pull is very limited and rely on expressions to fill in the blanks, this is one of them also. The only data that is pulled is the employee number and we usually reference off a word doc or by memory.

Comment: Only tag the database you are actually using i.e. pick the correct one. And in such a legacy system it seems what you have is probably as good as it gets.